# SharePoint CSOM ExecuteQuery Intermittent 503

Tags: 2013, csom

I have a section of code that goes and gets all of the documents within a document set based on document id. This code will typically function correctly but intermittently it will receive a 503 Server Unavailable error on a clientContext.ExecuteQuery. The SharePoint server does not show a 503 error in any of the logs(IIS, HTTPERR, Event Log, Failed Trace) nor in a WireShark trace. All I am seeing are random 401 errors with the last one occuring right before a TCP reset that comes from my workstation. Any thoughts? Here is the code that gets the document set and data:

```
 List<DTO.DocumentModel> documentList = new List<DTO.DocumentModel>();
        using (var context = GetClientContext())
        {
            string DocumentLibraryName = pLibraryName;
            context.RequestTimeout = 1000*30*8;

            var web = context.Web;
            var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(DocumentLibraryName);
            var query = new CamlQuery();
            query.ViewXml = @"<View scope='RecursiveAll'>
                <Query>
                    <Where>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name='_dlc_DocId'/><Value Type='Text'>" + pDocSetId + @"</Value>
                        </Eq>
                    </Where>
                </Query>
              </View>";

            var item = list.GetItems(query);

            context.Load(web);
            context.Load(list, l => l.RootFolder, l => l.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);
            context.Load(item);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            context.Load(item[0], d => d.Folder, d => d.Folder.ServerRelativeUrl);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            var docSet = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(item[0].Folder.ServerRelativeUrl);
            context.Load(docSet, d => d.Files, d => d.ServerRelativeUrl, d => d.ListItemAllFields.ContentType);

            context.ExecuteQuery();
            //spClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            if (docSet.Files.Count > 0)
            { 
                var results = new List<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File>();
                foreach (var doc in docSet.Files)
                {
                    context.Load(doc, d => d.ListItemAllFields, d => d.ListItemAllFields.ContentType, d => d.ListItemAllFields.FieldValuesAsText["Editor"]);
                    results.Add(doc);
                }
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                    documentList.Add(new DTO.DocumentModel()
                    {
                        DocId = result.ListItemAllFields["_dlc_DocId"].ToString(),
                        Name = result.Name,
                        ContentType = result.ListItemAllFields.ContentType.Name,
                        Link = result.ServerRelativeUrl,
                        EditLink = (string)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SPAccessURL"] + list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Forms/" + docSet.ListItemAllFields.ContentType.Name + "/docsethomepage.aspx?RootFolder=" + docSet.ServerRelativeUrl + "&DocToOpen=" + result.Name,
                        ModifiedDate = result.TimeLastModified.ToShortDateString(),
                        ModifiedBy = result.ListItemAllFields.FieldValuesAsText["Editor"],
                        DocSetId = pDocSetId

                    });
                }
            }
            return documentList;
        }
```

Comment: Do you know on which ExecuteQuery it fails?

Comment: It is random on which one it fails. But always the 503 error.

Comment: Think I may have figured out the issue. After doing another WireShark trace from my local dev machine and seeing the 503 error and followed the TCP trail. It turns out that the 503 was a "Virus/Spyware Download Block". Will report back if this ends up being the issue.

Comment: On which device you are running this script? Have you set any firewalls, antiviruses (company) etc.?